# Raid device on rename appended with _0

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I am creating various raid configurations. 
When I create a raid device say 5 with 3 disks

```
mdadm --create /dev/md/md5 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

It does create a device

```
/dev/md/md5
```

On reboot it is renamed to

```
/dev/md/md5_0
```

Why ? and What is _0 ?
I am fine with it. I just want to know asking why?

Comment: Do this: cat /proc/mdstat Are any other mdX devices being used?

Comment: No there are no mdX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the `homehost` setting.

From: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/mdadm.conf.5.html

> When arrays are assembled using auto-assembly, arrays
>   which  do not record the correct homehost name in their metadata
>   will be assembled using a  "foreign"  name.   A  "foreign"  name
>   alway  ends  with  a  digit  string preceded by an underscore to
>   differentiate it from any possible local name. e.g.  /dev/md/1_1
>   or /dev/md/home_0.

According to the docs, setting `HOMEHOST <ignore>` in `mdadm.conf` should be enough to disable this behavior, but on Ubuntu, you also need to run `update-initramfs -u` to update initramfs so it contains your `mdadm.conf` settings during boot.